# Phabricator rewrite rules configuring issue

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, phabricator

I'm having trouble installing phabricator. It actually seems like it would be a simple thing. I copied the example code exactly.

apache2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  # Change this to the domain which points to your host.
  ServerName localhost

  # Change this to the path where you put 'phabricator' when you checked it
  # out from GitHub when following the Installation Guide.
  #
  # Make sure you include "/webroot" at the end!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/phabricator/webroot

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>


<Directory "/var/www/phabricator/webroot">
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Whenever I go to the server IP on a browser, it gives me this error:

```
Request parameter '__path__' is not set. Your rewrite rules are not configured correctly.
```

I found that this was part of the phabricator code:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['__path__'])) {
    self::didFatal(
        "Request parameter '__path__' is not set. Your rewrite rules ".
        "are not configured correctly.");
}
```

Anyone have any idea how to get past this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but none of the answers helped me. Can anyone help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344737/phabricator-install-rewrite-rules-are-not-configured-correctly

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Phab and solved it with the following:

1. Place the Directory segment inside the VirtualHost segment.
2. Are you running any other Virtual Server in your system? If so, specify the port `*:80` (Or try a different one *Remember adding `Listen 8081` before declaring the VirtualHost segment if you try another port*)
3. And last replace the content of the Directory segment with this:

   ```
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   ```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but none of the answers helped me. Can anyone help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344737/phabricator-install-rewrite-rules-are-not-configured-correctly

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue. 
Just place

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
```

and remove following line from your `apache2.conf`.

```
RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me by just using the first line on a Webmin/Virtualmin server :)

It is also written in documentation, but I was to blind to see it.

Comment: I'm following the guide and trying to install this on GoDaddy shared hosting. I am getting the path not set problem. I don't have access to the apache2.conf and I tried putting this in an .htaccess file but then I get a server 500 error instead. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but none of the answers helped me. Can anyone help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344737/phabricator-install-rewrite-rules-are-not-configured-correctly