# Phabricator install. Rewrite rules are not configured correctly

Tags: php, apache, apache2, phabricator

I've followed the Phabricator [Configuration Guide](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuration_guide/), and after installing all dependencies, I'm facing the following message:

```
Request parameter '__path__' is not set. Your rewrite rules are not configured correctly.
```

This message is shown when I try to access `www.cleverbit.com.br/phabricator/webroot/`

I have a `apache2.conf` file configured just the way the docs suggested:

```
    <VirtualHost *>
  # Change this to the domain which points to your host.
  ServerName cleverbit.com.br

  # Change this to the path where you put 'phabricator' when you checked it
  # out from GitHub when following the Installation Guide.
  #
  # Make sure you include "/webroot" at the end!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phabricator/webroot

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/phabricator/webroot">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

---

What's exactly wrong with my apache rewrite configuration?

Comment: what's the OS you installing on?

Comment: It's an Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache does not have inheritance inside Directory statements, so you also need the `AllowOverride All` line inside the Directory block for `/var/www/html/phabricator/webroot`.

To avoid confusion, I would get rid of the `/var/www` Directory block, unless you have another VirtualHost that uses it (in which case, you might want to move Phabricator out from that directory to avoid accidentally creating back doors).

Comment: I did just like you suggested: same problem :(
I edited my question with the new apache2.conf

Comment: If I go to http://www.cleverbit.com.br/ I see a message about PHP 7.0 being unsupported.  You need to use PHP 7.1 or later (5.x used to also work, but I don't know if that is still the case)

Comment: Actually, now I'm having a "[Core Exception/Exception] Define 'phabricator.base-uri' in your configuration to continue.". Since this is not the main subject of the question, I'll give you the bounty. @JSON do you know whats is this problem now?:

Comment: If you use http, you need to explicitly set phabricator.base-uri, as the default is to use https (which you should consider - letsencrypt is free and easy to set up).  You can do this from the command-line: `/var/www/html/phabricator/bin/config set phabricator.base-uri "http://www.cleverbit.com.br/"`

Answer (score 0):

Setting the following rewrite rules fixed this for me

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
```

thanks to https://gist.github.com/sparrc/b4eff48a3e7af8411fc1